# How to Send Data Using NFC Between Android And WindowsPhone

Tags: java, c#, android, windows-phone-8, nfc

i searched a lot about this but i don't know how can I beam a Text String to WindowsPhone Device but i can do it From WindowsPhone To Android.

here is the code I'm using to Send Message From WindowsPhone to Android :

```
ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
// Make sure NFC is supported
if (device!= null)
{
   long Id = device.PublishMessage("Windows.MessageFromWindowsPhoneToAndroid", "Test");
}
```

also i found a code in C# to receive a NFC Message :

```
ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
// Make sure NFC is supported
if (device!= null)
{
   long Id = device.SubscribeForMessage ("Windows.NFCBeamMSGFromAndroid", messageReceived);
}

private void messageReceived(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Message Received");
   Debug.WriteLine("Received from {0}:'{1}'", sender.DeviceId, message.DataAsString);
}
```

i test the send NFC message Function For WindowsPhone and i see the message *("MessageFromWindowsPhoneToAndroid")* in Tags Application.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you want to create a [NDEFRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html) with a TNF of TNF_WELL_KNOWN and Type RTD_TEXT.

The payload is bytes and must be encoded with languageCodeLength, languageCode, text. The payload "hello, world" encoded with the language code "en" would be [2, 101, 110, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

Put this NDEFRecord into a [NDEFMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html) and share via [NFCAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(message, activity)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage(android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...));